# bash source a file that has an exit command at the end

Tags: bash, shell

```
cat >file1.sh <<'EOF_FILE1'
  echo 'before source'
  source 'file2.sh'
  echo 'after source'
  func1
EOF_FILE1

cat >file2.sh <<'EOF_FILE2'
  echo 'test script'
  func1() {
    echo 'func1 starts'
    exit
  }
  exit
EOF_FILE2

bash file1.sh
```

Intended output is:

```
before source
test script
after source
func1 starts
```

Actual output is:

```
before source
test script
```

The 'after source' is missing due to the `exit` command. Is there a way around this since I can not remove `exit` from the code?

Comment: Why are you using `source` to run a program that clearly isn't written / intended by its author to be executed that way? (That's an important question, because if we don't know what you're trying to accomplish, we don't know whether the side effects of various approaches/answers are acceptable; if you need to access variables or functions set by the script, for example, anything that puts the script in a subshell or subprocess is unacceptable unless paired with a means of extracting those values).

Comment: Conversely, `file2.sh` may incorrectly be using `exit` if it is intended to be sourced.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, making it clear which aspects of `source`'s behavior you need to retain.

Comment: BTW, it would be helpful if you had a final line in `file1.sh`, either `echo "this should be run"` or `echo "this should not be run"`, letting us know whether the `exit` inside `func1` is supposed to survive.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, it's good form to only use `.sh` in the name of a script if it's built with the intention of being sourced by any POSIX-compliant shell (or to use no extension at all if it's intended to be executed and not sourced; or to use a `.bash` extension if it's intended to be sourced only by bash). That way something written to be invoked as an executable can be rewritten in any other language without changing its callers; and doesn't falsely imply that it can be sourced into a POSIX interpreter if it's written only for bash.

Answer (score 4):

Whereas the *best* approach is to write scripts that are intended to be sourced rather than executed with that use case in mind, if you can't do that for whatever reason, you might consider `alias`ing `exit` to `return` before the `source` command, as follows:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases  # enable alias expansion (off by default in noninteractive shells)
alias exit=return        # ...and alias 'exit' to 'return'

source 'file2.sh'        # source in your file which incorrectly uses 'exit' at top-level
unalias exit             # disable the alias...
echo 'after source'
func1
```

---

If you want the `exit` in your function to still take effect when that function is called, things can be made a little more complex:

```
maybe_exit() {
  local last_retval=$?                 # preserve exit's behavior of defaulting to $?
  [[ $do_not_really_exit ]] && return  # abort if flag is set
  (( $# )) && exit "$@"                # if arguments are given, pass them through
  exit "$last_retval"                  # otherwise, use the $? we captured above
}

shopt -s expand_aliases  # enable alias expansion (off by default in noninteractive shells)
alias exit=maybe_exit    # ...and alias 'exit' to 'maybe_exit'

do_not_really_exit=1     # set a flag telling maybe_exit not to really exit
source 'file2.sh'        # source in your file which incorrectly uses 'exit' at top-level
unset do_not_really_exit # clear that flag...
unalias exit             # disable the alias...
echo 'after source'
func1
```

Answer (score 3):

**[`source`](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) executes `file2.sh` inside the same shell that runs `file1.sh`.**

---

You might want to use the [**`bash`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) command instead, so that a new shell is spawned for executing `file2.sh`:

```
echo 'before source'
bash file2.sh
echo 'after source'
```

***OR***

As suggested by @CharlesDuffy [**in the comments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063180/bash-source-a-file-that-has-an-exit-command-at-the-end/52063262?noredirect=1#comment91077367_52063262), you can use `(source file2.sh)` to source `file2.sh` in a subshell. This would isolate the code in the subprocess, but lets it access non-exported shell variables, like any other `source`d' script can do. It also consumes less resources.

```
echo 'before source'
(source file2.sh)
echo 'after source'
```

Comment: More efficient to source it in a subshell: `(source file2.sh)` still isolates the code in the subprocess so it can't exit the main shell (and with the same side effect of not letting shell variables set in the script persist past its end -- if the reason the OP is `source`ing the script is to access such variables, this answer thus may be unsuitable), but lets it access non-exported shell variables (like any other `source`d script can do), and doesn't pay the full cost of spinning up a new shell via an `exec`-family syscall.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is great! I edited my answer, thanks.